# Extracting sub string using Perl

Tags: perl

I have string as follows.

```
{
"id": "1304145"
,"Name" : "Ravi"
,"State" : "KAR"
,"Comp" : "CTL"
}
,{
"id": "2488398"
,"Name" : "Abhik"
,"State" : "TEL"
,"Comp" : "WFG"
}
,{
"id": "89039487"
,"Name" : "Jana"
,"State" : "ODS"
,"Comp" : "TOT"
}
```

I want to extract each of the sub-string present in a {} and make a format as follws

```
ID          Name    State   Comp
1304145     Ravi    KAR     CTL
2488398     Abhik   TEL     WFG
89039487    Jana    ODS     TOT
```

I tried it, but my scripts are not giving the exact outputs.
Need your help in solving this.

Comment: Looks like JSON. You should use a Parser for JSON

Comment: Please show all the scripts that you have tried. It's usually much easier to fix existing code than to write something from scratch, it will help you to learn if someone explains what you have done wrong, and it's rather cheeky to expect us to write a solution for you.

Comment: You should show us both your scripts, and what sort of wrong output they are producing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks a lot like JSON.

If it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all'; 

use JSON;

my $json = from_json(do{local $/;<DATA>});

my @header = qw ( id Name State Comp ); 

print join ( "\t", @header ), "\n"; 

foreach my $row ( @$json ) { 
    print join ( "\t",@{$row}{@header} ),"\n";
}

__DATA__
[{
"id": "1304145"
,"Name" : "Ravi"
,"State" : "KAR"
,"Comp" : "CTL"
},
{
"id": "2488398"
,"Name" : "Abhik"
,"State" : "TEL"
,"Comp" : "WFG"
}
,{
"id": "89039487"
,"Name" : "Jana"
,"State" : "ODS"
,"Comp" : "TOT"
}
]
```

Gives:

```
id  Name    State   Comp
1304145 Ravi    KAR CTL
2488398 Abhik   TEL WFG
89039487    Jana    ODS TOT
```

That's assuming that you do have JSON though - I had to add `[]` around your snippet. If it isn't `JSON` then someone's done something dirty, in creating something that looks a lot like JSON, but that isn't.

Comment: yep, will not work without the list brackets, so either OP didn't include them in the input, or whatever created the input is reinventing the JSON wheel, incorrectly.

Comment: Yes. Anyone who generates 'almost JSON, but not quite' needs to be smacked around the head with a rolled up copy of the spec :)

Comment: hard copy if the implementation is destined for prod, and not just purely educational ;)

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason the data *isn't* supposed to be JSON, and the keys and values are *always* enclosed in double-quotes, then you can parse it easily with regular expressions

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';


my $s = <<END_STRING;
{
"id": "1304145"
,"Name" : "Ravi"
,"State" : "KAR"
,"Comp" : "CTL"
}
,{
"id": "2488398"
,"Name" : "Abhik"
,"State" : "TEL"
,"Comp" : "WFG"
}
,{
"id": "89039487"
,"Name" : "Jana"
,"State" : "ODS"
,"Comp" : "TOT"
}
END_STRING

my @data = map { { /"([^"]*)"/g } } $s =~ /\{[^{}]*\}/g;

my $fmt = "%-11s %-7s %-7s %s\n";

printf $fmt, qw/ ID Name State Comp /;
for my $item ( @data ) {
    printf $fmt, @{$item}{qw/ id Name State Comp /};
}
```

#### output

```
ID          Name    State   Comp
1304145     Ravi    KAR     CTL
2488398     Abhik   TEL     WFG
89039487    Jana    ODS     TOT
```